# Addressing Decoherence in Quantum Key Distribution (QKD)

Tags: quantum-mechanics

How does one address Quantum decoherence during Quantum Key Distribution (QKD)?

Does Quantum decoherence affect QKD?

Nathan Aw

Comment: Did you mean to write QKD in your second line? If not then these are 2 completely unrelated questions and should be posted separately (although "how does decoherence effect QED is probably too broad a question to answer)

Comment: apologies! QKD. I have edited.